# Rational Function,

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

A curve has equation $y=\frac{x^2-5}{x^2+2x-11}$.

How to prove algebraically that there are no values of $x$ for which $\frac{1}{2}<y<\frac{5}{6}$?

Answer (score 3):

We have
$$y(x^2+2x-11)=x^2-5\Rightarrow (y-1)x^2+2yx-11y+5=0.$$
Then, since $x$ is real, the discriminant has to be non-negative.

Comment: So the ranges of $x$ is $x\leq \frac{1}{2}$ or $x\geq \frac{5}{6}$. What's the meaning of this?

Comment: @Mathxx: No, $y\le \frac 12$ or $y\ge \frac 56$.

Comment: @Mathxx: There exist real $x$ such that $(y-1)x^2+2yx-11y+5=0$ iff the discriminant $(2y)^2-4(y-1)(-11y+5)$ is non-negative.